# C - variables in header file not recognized

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I'm new to C and I'm trying to create an online grocery store where I can add items to the store and print the details of each product such as the name, number in stock, price, etc.

I'm having trouble adding a product to a product collection array and getting it to print. My biggest issue is that **main.c** seems to not recognize practically every variable declared in **defs.h** even though I used the include tag at the top of the file. I'm also not sure if my `addProd()` function makes sense and was hoping someone could verify?

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "defs.h"

int main(){

    InventoryType store;
    store.storeName = "Walmart";
    
    ProductCollectionType p;
    p.numProd = 0;
    
    addProd(&p, 1001, "Grape juice", 12.5);
    addProd(&p, 1002, "Pepsi", 4.3);
    addProd(&p, 1003, "Apples", 34.0);

    int choice;
    printf("(1) Print inventory");
    printf("(0) Exit");

    printf(" ");
    printf("Please enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", choice);
    if(choice == 1){
        store->printInventory(p)
    } 
    return 0;
}

void printInventory(ProductCollectionType* productArray){
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < numProd; ++i) {
        printf("The BLANK store");
        printf("-- Product #%d, %s, %d units, $ %.2f", productArray[i].id, productArray[i]->name, productArray[i].numUnits, productArray[i].price);
    }
}

int addProd(ProductCollectionType* productArray, int givenId, char givenName, int givenUnits, float givenPrice){
    for(i = 0; i < numProd; ++i){
        productArray[i].id = givenId;
        productArray[i].name = givenName;
        productArray[i].numUnits = givenUnits;
        productArray[i].price = givenPrice;
    }
}
```

**defs.h**

```
#define MAX_NAME 40
#define MAX_PROD 20
#define MAX_UNITS 15
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char *name;
    int numUnits;
    float price;
}ProductType;

typedef struct {
    ProductType* products[MAX_UNITS];
    int numProd;
    int nextId; 
}ProductCollectionType;

typedef struct{
    char *storeName;
    ProductCollectionType* productArray[MAX_PROD];
}InventoryType;
```

Comment: That's just a code dump. Please indicate exactly where is the compilation (or runtime) error is.

Comment: BTW, those are not actual variables declared in your header file (which is good, because you should avoid doing that anyway).

Comment: Basically in every function where I try to use the variable. So for example, the first error is in the print function and it says numProd is undeclared. This is the same for when I try to print out certain details of a product like productArray[i].numUnits where it says numUnits is undeclared.

Comment: Well, that's because `numProd` is indeed not declared anywhere (even in your header file, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code:

```
void printInventory(ProductCollectionType* productArray){
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < numProd; ++i){
        blah blah blah
```

There is no such thing as the "naked" `numProd`, `numProd` is a field of the `ProductCollectionType` type. Hence you would need something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < productArray->numProd; ++i) {
```